# Failed deployment of Azure Function Bot

Tags: azure, botframework, cortana, azure-bot-service

I have recently created a new subscription on Azure in order to use the Bot Service to develop Cortana skills, by following the instructions that can be found on the official documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-quickstart

However, every time I try to create a new Function Bot (with .NET templates), deployment fails with a rather inexplicable error: "InvalidBotData - Id: Id is already in use..".
I have also tried to create a Function Bot by logging in from the Bot Framework portal -> Create a bot with Azure Bot Service, with the same results.
Furthermore, even if the deployment fails, a Function App instance is actually created (I can see it in the resource recap on the main Azure dashboard), although this Function App seems to lack some of the typical features and properties of standard bot services, since for example I can't find the "Test in Web Chat" feature (indeed, the whole "Bot Management" section is missing).
Even the icon itself of the created Function App instance is different from the icon that is displayed in the official documentation for Function Bots.
Am I doing something wrong? Is the official documentation actually up-to-date? Is there any other, more complete tutorial addressing these kind of issue?
Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: You need to contact Azure support via the Azure portal website to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and contacted Azure support. They said to make sure you don't use any reserved MSFT words in your Bot name. My bot name started with "skype", which is protected within their system. After I changed the name to exclude "skype" from it, everything worked as expected. You probably used "cortana" in yours, that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: Right!! I used "cortana" in the bot name.. ehehe.. Thanks!!